# Linear Regression

Tags: matplotlib, linear-regression

My Problem Statement is : 
The following data set shows the result of recently conducted study on the correlation of the number of hours spent driving with the risk of developing acute back pain. Find the equation of the best fit line for this data.

Data set is as below :

```
x   y
10  95
9   80
2   10
15  50
10  45
16  98
11  38
16  93
```

Machine spec : Linux Ubuntu 18.10 64bit

I am having some error:

```
python LR.py
Accuracy :
43.70948145101002
[6.01607946]
Enter the no of hours10
y :
0.095271*10.000000+5.063367
Risk Score :  6.016079463451905
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "LR.py", line 30, in <module>
plt.plot(X,y,'o')
File "/home/sumeet/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3358, in plot
ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sumeet/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1855, in inner
return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sumeet/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1527, in plot
for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
File "/home/sumeet/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 406, in _grab_next_args
for seg in self._plot_args(this, kwargs):
File "/home/sumeet/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 383, in _plot_args
x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
File "/home/sumeet/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 242, in _xy_from_xy
"have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have 
shapes (8, 1) and (1,)
```

The code is as below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Read Dataset
dataset=pd.read_csv("hours.csv")
X=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,1].values

# Import the Linear Regression and Create object of it
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor=LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X,y)
Accuracy=regressor.score(X, y)*100
print("Accuracy :")
print(Accuracy)

# Predict the value using Regressor Object
y_pred=regressor.predict([[10]])
print(y_pred)

# Take user input
hours=int(input('Enter the no of hours'))

#calculate the value of y
eq=regressor.coef_*hours+regressor.intercept_
y='%f*%f+%f' %(regressor.coef_,hours,regressor.intercept_)
print("y :")
print(y)
print("Risk Score : ", eq[0])
plt.plot(X,y,'o')
plt.plot(X,regressor.predict(X));
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the beginning of your code, you define the `y` which you probably want to plot:

```
y=dataset.iloc[:,1].values
```

but further down, you re-define (and thus overwriting) it as

```
y='%f*%f+%f' %(regressor.coef_,hours,regressor.intercept_)
```

which causes the error, as this last `y` is a string and not an array with 8 elements like `X` (and like your initial `y`).

Change it with something else, e.g. `Y`, at the relevant lines in the end:

```
Y='%f*%f+%f' %(regressor.coef_,hours,regressor.intercept_)
print("Y :")
print(Y)
```

so as to keep your `y` as initially defined, and you should be fine.